# Setting AIR_ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable for Flash Builder / ADT

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I want to enable plugins for StageWebView and as Adobe described in the docs here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffc.html#WS365a66ad37c9f5102ec8a8ba12f2d91095a-8000

So I must point AIR Developer Tool (ADT) packager to a android sdk version >=3.0

It reads:

> You can also set the AIR_ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable to the
>   path containing the Android SDK.

But unfortunately, it doesn't give a single clue how to do this.

How do I set such environment variable?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 7 (others might be slightly different, but the general idea is the same) it is:

Start, right click on Computer, then Properties, then Advanced System Settings, Environment Variables.

There, you click 'New' and enter variable name (AIR_ANDROID_SDK_HOME) and value (full path to the directory).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I simply wasn't sure what was meant by "environment", the system or the IDE. As I'm on Mac I had to do some more research. The best way to do this could be found [here: ] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x/5444960#5444960)